# Grouping of Similar data by amount in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, range, grouping

I have a txn table with columns ac_id, txn_amt. It will store the data txn amounts along with account ids. Below is example of data

```
AC_ID      TXN_AMT
10         1000
10         1000
10         1010
10         1030
10         5000
10         5010
10         10000
20         32000
20         32200
20         5000
```

I want to write a query in such a way that all the amounts which are within 10% range of the previous amounts should be grouped together. Output should be something like this:

```
AC_ID  TOTAL_AMT  TOTAL_CNT GROUP
10     4040       4         1
10     10010      2         2
20     64200      2         3
20     5000       1         4
```

I tried with LAG function but still clueless. This is the code snippet I tried:

```
select ac_id, txn_amt, round((((txn_amt - lag(txn_amt, 1) over (partition by ac_id order by ac_id, txn_amt))/txn_amt)*100,2) as amt_diff_pct from txn;
```

Any clue or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define "previous amounts"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there are no *previous* rows, unless a column explicitly provides the ordering.

Comment: That;s why I am using LAG function, it's partitioning by ac_id and ordering by ac_id and txn_amt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by *previous* you mean "the largest amount less than", then you can do this.  You can find where the gaps are (i.e. larger than a 10% difference).  Then you can assign a group by counting the number of gaps:

```
select ac_id, sum(txn_amt) as total_amt, count(*) as total_cnt, grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_txn_amt * 1.1 > txn_amt then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by ac_id order by txn_amt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(txn_amt) over (partition by ac_id order by txn_amt) as prev_txn_amt
            from txn t
           ) t
     ) t
group by ac_id, grp;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.